# Remove Quotes from object using php

Tags: php, json

I have a json object.In that i need to remove double quotes.

```
{"1":{"1":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}","2":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}","3":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}"},"2":{"1":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}","2":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}","3":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}"},"3":{"1":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}","2":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}","3":"{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}"}}
```

I need to remove the Quotes from object.

```
{"1":{"1":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0},"2":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0},"3":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}},"2":{"1":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0},"2":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0},"3":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}},"3":{"1":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0},"2":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0},"3":{m:4,preference:1,r:0,tt:0}}}
```

I tried :
`json_decode($request),json_decode(json_encode($request))` 
but no result.it returns `null`.

Also i need to add quotes to keys

```
{"m":4,"preference":1,"r":0,"tt":0}
```

Comment: How is the initial JSON created? It may be better to fix this than try and re-process it.

Comment: this json is send from Android as a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to try make valid json on sender. But if you can't, use below code to manually parse source string $str

```
function like_json_decode($str) {
    $arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', $str));
    $new_arr = [];
    foreach ($arr as &$x) {
        $x = trim($x, ' {}');
        $x = array_map('trim', explode(':', $x));
        $new_arr[$x[0]] = $x[1];
    }
    return $new_arr;
}

$arr = json_decode($str, true);

foreach ($arr as &$subarr) {
    foreach($subarr as &$x) {
        $x = like_json_decode($x);
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/324443ae15a3d5b3b9f117d7789cb17ae6ef7086)